# flutter ./gradlew build fails for missing class

Tags: flutter, gradle, android-manifest, gradlew

I am trying to build my Flutter app for Android by running from the commandline:
./gradlew build

I am getting this error:

> Task :app:lintDebug FAILED
> Lint found 3 errors, 2 warnings. First failure:

.../android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:15: Error: Class referenced in the manifest, com.company.example.MainActivity, was not found in the project or the libraries [MissingClass]
android:name=".MainActivity"
~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Explanation for issues of type "MissingClass":
If a class is referenced in the manifest or in a layout file, it must also
exist in the project (or in one of the libraries included by the project.
This check helps uncover typos in registration names, or attempts to rename
or move classes without updating the XML references properly.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

My AndroidManifest.xml is as follows:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:label="example"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I tried many solutions and none worked.
Solution like:

flutter clean
flutter pub get

Also:
./gradlew clean

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks!